# Can we control Philips Hue lights with RaspberryPi based Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have seen multiple links  about controlling philips hue lights uisng Amazon Echo.  I wanted to know if we can do the same with self built alexa made using RaspberryPi instead of real amazon echo ?

Is there any difference between both ?

Regards
Kalyan

Answer (score 1):

You should try DIYhue on GitHub for all these functions. It contains direct Alexa and Philips Hue implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. As long as you have set up the RasberryPi to ask as an Alexa enabled device, all you have to do is connect it to your account, go to the Alexa phone app and discover your lights. Then it should work. It will also have all of the other functionality that Alexa has since all the RasberryPi is is a microphone and speaker and Alexa's logic is in the cloud.

Guides for this:

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-alexa/